# Как запаковать видео файл в бинарную строку?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь загрузить видео на Facebook по API, там пишут что им нужно передать видео файл в таком виде:

> multi-part form

[Документация по загрузке видео](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advideo/v4.0#create)

Я беру свой файл, зачитываю через fread и пытаюсь его так и отправить

```
$file = fopen($video_path, 'r');
$read = fread($file, $video_size);

$data = [
        'url'       => $url,
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => [
            'source'    => $read
        ],
        'headers'   => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    ];
```

Но Facebook не принимает, доходит до таймаута и обрывается соединение просто...

А если просто указать путь к файлу ( не зачитывая его через fread) - то фб пишет ошибку

> Загрузка вашего видео была прервана до завершения. Может быть медленное подключение к сети или видео, которое вы пытаетесь загрузить, слишком велико. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.

Как закодировать правильно видео чтобы отправить на Facebook?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $send_headers);
if( strlen($login) && strlen($password) ){
        $proxy_log_pass="{$login}:{$password}";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_log_pass);
    }

    if( $proxy_type == 'HTTP' ){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    }elseif( $proxy_type == 'SOCKS5' ){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    }elseif( $proxy_type == 'SOCKS4' ){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_data);
```

Есть еще запрос на загрузку изображения по этому же АПИ, там требуемый формат такой

```
$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
$params = [
    'bytes'     => $base64,
    'name'      => $image_name
];
```

Картинка пакуется в base64 и отправляется так, и все работает, картинка грузится.

Поэтому делаю вывод что я неправильно пакую видео

Comment: покажите код отправки что у вас там? curl\сокеты\что то еще?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков добавил в текст. Отправляю через CURL

Answer (score 0):

Отправил запрос через POSTMAN, выбрав там файл - и с постмана отправилось окей, вот что в коде выдал постман:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent- Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_phase\"\r\n\r\nfinish\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\nMyBigVideo\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_session_id\"\r\n\r\n434999506\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"waterfall_id\"\r\n\r\ne57dab6f68ab009a1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Accept: */*",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Content-Length: 561",
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------184115164164614855082341",
"Host: graph-video.facebook.com",
"Postman-Token: 1e89670c-1ff1-4c7c-b273-d5f2aacfec46,5f9213aa-e26c-427e-8b06-3dc3ad920cfa",
"User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
```

),

Comment: Дополнения к вопросу должно находится в вопросе, там есть кнопка "править".